# apex How set attribute to process dynamicly in other item dynamic action in js or pl/sql section?

Tags: javascript, excel, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I use Excel2Collection plugin (https://github.com/antonscheffer/excel2collections/tree/master/plugin) to download xls.

I need to load information from multiple tabs in my excel file (e.g. 1, 3, 8 or lists of attraction in 'London', 'Paris' and 'New-York' sheets).

I have installed the plugin and it is loading the file OK but only the data from 
 the first tab.

P.S. And please, if you put a minus to my question, please explain me why? English is not my native language. So please, tell me where I made a grammatical or spelling mistake(s) or failed to complete the question. I searched everywhere in documentation and on the Internet and found no answer. Help me if you can.

Comment: Hi Lora, this site is not a place to get others to write the code for you, please show what you have tried, what is not working / what errors you are getting so that we can assist you.

Comment: So where I ask write code for me? I can load only first page. I have process witch use file browse and buttons to load xls into apex and translate it into oracle table, and grid for see what I load. I wrote many code, despite I install (and see) apex on last week. It's only part of my task.

Comment: Thank you for remove downvote. I create select list to load tabs names, but I don't know how it fill. I try to get process attribute settings -> sheets by $x("process_name").Settings.Sheets (undef) in select list DA, but in variable $x("process_name") is false.

Comment: alert(JSON.stringify(apex.item("process_name")));
And I get {"node":false,"item_type":false,"id":false,"delayLoading":false,"callbacks":{}}

Comment: Every sheet in your file go to distinct collections, if you called your collection 'DEMO'. So the first sheet go to the collection 'DEMO', the second sheet to 'DEMO2', the third to 'DEMO3'.

Comment: I was just about to make this comment - how do you know only one tab was loaded? Check for collections as romeu suggested

Comment: It doesn't work. I can only load, that in process -> settengs ->sheets. And only 1 page! There is no addition collection.